# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Home Improvement's [third moderator election](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Niall C.]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5583069864001536/0).

Also, I'd like to wish a fond farewell to [Vebjorn Ljosa](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/21/vebjorn-ljosa), one of the original elected moderators who is stepping down this year. Please join me in thanking them for their service and wishing them all the best in their future adventures.

Comment: Many thanks to Verbjorn for his service, a round of applause to all the candidates that ran, and a congratulations to Niall C. We're looking forward to having you on the team.